# Why don't we see any ballistae?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In the Season 7 finale of Game of Thrones, *The Dragon and the Wolf*

> The Unsullied and Dothraki arrive in King's Landing, while the Lannisters prepare defenses for a siege. But there aren't any ballistae on the walls, even if it's their only way to hurt/kill dragons. 
>  
>   [image: No balistae]
> <sub>(source: [wetpaint.com](https://www.wetpaint.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/game-of-thrones-season-7-finale-01.jpg))</sub>

So, why don't we see any ballistae?

Comment: Maybe they are hidden like they were during Dany's assault on Lannister train. Or maybe they are not deployed on the Walls but rather inside the city at strategic points such as the three hills (Aegon's, Visenya's and Rhaenys') like Siege weaponry was deployed inside the city during battle of Black Water bay.

Comment: I can see Aegon's hill in your picture, but not Rhaenys' nor Visenya's. Why give up the position of your most prized weapons? For all they knew, Dany could have launched a recon flight on high altitude.

Comment: True, in the book, the trebuchet were **behind** the mud gate (dont remember how xhere trebuchets in the tv show though). Still, unlike battle of Black Water bay where we knew where will stannis go, as there is only one way, the Blackwater, Daenerys can strike from everywhere, so you can't put the balistae on only one point, but have to spread it everywhere.

Comment: indeed and most important point which needs airdefense is Aegon's hill. And unlike Stannis, Dany can have a peek beyond the high walls of KL and mark her targets. Which makes it all the more necessary that Dany shouldn't find the locations of the most dangerous weapons in Lannister arsenal (Other than wildfire)

Comment: Voted to close as Primarily Opinion Based because as of now no information is given. If information shows up we can re-open the question.

Comment: Considering what we know now I'm just going to guess that they weren't there because they hadn't been built yet.